# How to tab-autocomplete latex commands into the equivalent unicode character?

Tags: visual-studio-code, unicode, latex, quarto

When editing a Julia `.jl` file, I'm able to type, say, `\alpha` followed the tab key and produce the symbol α. This is the same behavior as from within the Julia REPL.

How do I enable similar autocompletion in `qmd` files?